# Python - Do math from url parameters

Tags: python, json, parsing, url

My goal simply this:

The url is something like: /add?a=1&b=2

My function should get the value of these parameters and simply do addition. However, I'm actually stuck on how to accomplish this. Here's all I have for my add function:

```
def add():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    c = a + b
    return json.dumps({'c':c})
```

So if /add?a=1&b=2 it should return:

```
{"c": 3}
```

Not

```
{"c": 1}
```

Comment: Is it guaranteed that the query parameters are `a` and `b` (and the result is `c`)?  Do you need to parse the url yourself (the stdlib has lots of tools to make this pretty easy), or are you using a framework which handles this for you?

Comment: Yes, a & b will always be the parameters and the result should be stored in c. the framework I'm using is web2py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You don't describe the question clearly:</s>

whether you simply want a parse function to extract parameters from url string and do math;

or want to make a request to this url and get the result as response.

As you mentioned web2py in the comment, then it should be the second one. I don't have web2py experience, but I think it may be similar with flask.

Take Flask as an example. You need to add a handler for `/add`. I will ignore the import.

```
@app.route('/add')
def add():
    a, b = request.args['a'], request.args['b']
    c = a + b
    return json.dumps({'c': c})
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's built-in `urllib.parse` has support for parsing the URL itself. Then, as you have, you can use `json.dumps` to output it in that format.

```
from urllib.parse import parse_qs, splitquery
from json import dumps

def add(url):
    data = parse_qs(splitquery(url)[1])
    a = int(data['a'][0])
    b = int(data['b'][0])
    c = a + b
    return dumps({'c': c})

add("/add?a=1&b=2")
# '{"c": 3}'
```